# Predicting the superconductor critical temperature

Tags: superconductivity

I am fairly new to superconductors, but am attempting to understand BCS theory. Is BCS Theory, or any other tested theories of superconductivity currently capable of predicting the transition temperature when the material becomes superconducting?